# Request.Form.Count is 0 when calling aspx page

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, post

i am trying to post to an aspx page using form post below is the code.Where as value is going but request.form.count is '0'. Therefore i am not able to call a method in requested page.Well this works on local host but not on iis.

Comment: Does changing to `onload='alert(1)'` works ?

Comment: Also what about the response mime type which should be text/html ?

Comment: Nope @RoyiNamir